# Xcode 6: Slow as molasses in Alaska

Tags: xcode6

I finally "upgraded" to Xcode 6. However, it is painfully slow. If I build; run; stop; run (without changes) it takes several minutes.

Is there something that can speed up the Xcode build time?

In the past, if I re-ran without making changes, the startup was almost instantaneous.

Could some setting be off here?

Searching here, I found assorted complaints about slowness but not this specific one (a surprise to me).

Comment: seriously.i agree with you :(

Comment: What kind of deployment/target are you using?  It looks like a problem doing unneeded full builds.

Comment: I generally use the iPhone 4 simulator, simply because it fits the screen best. I have used other simulators and devices with the same.

Comment: Using a new MacBook 15 inch Retina, with 6, launches like a rocket in the simulator. My old MacBook, took forever. Now at least 10X faster. Gets down to hardware.

Comment: I add that I do not get a blue progress bar at all while rerunning, like I do when building. It just takes forever to start.

Comment: After it compiles, it spends 3-4 minutes "Building Application Map before running.